# Can using strncpy to copy tcp stream cause malfunction?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am making a simple proxy server. And I have a very hard time with parsing response.

```
// Case 1
do {
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    con = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
    write(client, buffer, con);
} while(con);

// Case 2
do {
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    con = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
    size += con;
    cachebuf = (char*)realloc(cachebuf, size);
    strncpy(cachebuf+(size-con), buffer, con);
} while(con);
write(client, cachebuf, size);
```

These two samples receive a TCP stream from the end server, and forward it to browser. The only difference is that first one forwards the stream as soon as it receives it, and second one saves the stream in the cachebuf pointer and sends as a whole(which it the case I want to use)

It seems same, and both works fine when it receives a HTML file. However, the second one can not send images. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `strncpy` (and friends) to copy binary data. This function copies bytes until it encounters nul-terminator (`'\0'`). Binary data, in particularly, images, have a lot of those characters in them, and string functions will not copy it completely.

To copy binary data, you can use `memcpy` or `std::copy`.

On a side note, your `memset` before `read` is completely unnecessary and just contributes to global warming without doing anything useful.

Comment: And if James would realloc his size plus BUFSIZE the code could just call read() with the current buffer, saving the cost of memcpy.

Comment: @ZanLynx this is true, but since the whole idea of intermediate realloc'ed buffer is not clear to me, I just assumed it's an artifact of an actual problem and left it as is.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood that strncpy always copies exactly n characters.

Comment: @Zan Lynx Thanks for advice. That's a great idea